# how to lead my imageMagick to support wmf format(windows)?

Tags: c++, format, imagemagick, wmf, magick++

I use Magick++ api in windows. When i read a wmf file,my program crashed.The problem is that my imageMagick doesn't support wmf format? Can someone teach me how to lead my imageMagick to support wmf format?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php  It says WMF support requires libwmf, so perhaps that is a direction to try.

Comment: I have installed libwmf and reinstall the imageMagick.but is doesn't work.

Comment: What's more,other format are all supported.For example SVG format,but I haven't install librsvg and libxml2 to support it.